# AEM 61. Class CQ.Ext.form.DateField select no future days

Tags: aem, datefield

Hello I am trying to Configure in AEM 6.1 that my date picker will not allow me to select future dates, only past and current

Class CQ.Ext.form.DateField

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, adding the `maxValue` property should take care of this. However, I noticed that it doesn't work in AEM 6.1. As a workaround you can add the following listener to your `datefield` and set the current date as the `maxValue`.

```
<date jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
      fieldLabel="Date" 
      name="./date" 
      xtype="datefield">
      <listeners 
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
          loadcontent="function(comp) {  comp.setMaxValue(new Date()); }"/>
</date>
```